# Copy a work item and specific related work items

Tags: tfs

TFS 2010 has a built copy work item functionality. I was wondering if anyone knew of a tool exists that can take this feature a little bit further. I'd like to be able to copy a work item **plus** other specific related work items and the links to those work items.

[This](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/cd89c5d3-4816-4f22-b04e-a397cc606be6) almost does exactly what I need, except it doesn't copy across projects.

Comment: I don't know of any tools that will do this as you need it to. You could however invent your own wheel using the TFS libraries to recreate the work items across various projects. You would of course have to ensure that the work item types are available in all of the projects in your TFS server otherwise you won't be able to create items of the type you are copying. Does that make sense?

Comment: If needed, I have some code from VSTS2008 that works with TFS work items.

Comment: @Duncan yeah, I've been working on this actually, I've just about finished it. It's not particularly difficult, there is just the caveat, you've already mentioned, of making sure the work item type exists in the other project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I'm using at work: http://tfsintegration.codeplex.com/  (Actually, we're using the supported version at http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f854dd59-8eeb-4673-8d9a-ae012989bfa2).

It can be configured to copy from one team project to another on the same server easily.  Work item types do not have to be identical, you can define transformations if necessary.

If you need to extend something, this is what I would recommend starting with.